# Is there a way to call toPrimitive in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to call toPrimitive on a value in Javascript?

**Why?**

I'm using Proxy in my project.

```
function makeProxy(unknown_value) {
    let proxy_target = ()=>{};
    proxy_target.inner = unknown_value;
    proxy_target.my_data = 123456;

    return new Proxy(proxy_target, some_proxy_handler);
}

let proxied_value = makeProxy(<? something unknown ?>);
```

This proxy redirects all the calls to "inner".
And eventually I was stroke by something like this:

```
console.log(1+proxied_value);
```

Here Javascript calls

```
(1)
proxied_value.get(proxy_target, Symbol.toPrimitive)
```

Because Javascript wants to try to convert proxied_value to some value to perform "+" for it. And this operation IS possible for proxy_target.inner

So I want to redirect this call (1) to:

```
(something like)
Object.toPrimitive( proxy_target.inner );
```

But I found no way to call toPrimitive directly.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, based on searching the spec for all references to ToPrimitive, there doesn't seem to be any option other than tediously reimplementing the algorithm in javascript.

A (mostly untested) example implementation might be:

```js
// a primitive is anything that's not an object, but typeof has two quirks
// to be cautious of:
//    - for a callable object it returns 'function' rather than 'object'
//    - typeof null is 'object' even though null is a primitive
const isPrimitive = ( value ) =>
    typeof value === 'object' ? value === null : typeof value !== 'function';

const toPrimitive = ( value, hint='default' ) => {
    // if value is already a primitive, we're done
    if( isPrimitive( value ) )
        return value;

    // if value[ Symbol.toPrimitive ] exists (is not undefined or null)
    let method = value[ Symbol.toPrimitive ];
    if( method != null ) {  // using != instead of !== is intentional

        // then call value[ Symbol.toPrimitive ]( hint )
        let result = Reflect.apply( method, value, [ hint ] );
        if( isPrimitive( result ) )
            return result;

        // if it doesn't return a primitive, do not fall back to legacy
        // methods but just throw an error

    } else {

        // if value[ Symbol.toPrimitive ] doesn't exist, try the legacy
        // valueOf() and toString() methods, in that order unless hint
        // is 'string' in which case toString() is tried first.
        //
        // for these we need to be more garbage-tolerant:  if the first
        // legacy method is a non-function or returns a non-primitive,
        // just ignore it and move on to the second one.

        method = value[ hint === 'string' ? 'toString' : 'valueOf' ];
        if( typeof method === 'function' ) {
            let result = Reflect.apply( method, value, [] );
            if( isPrimitive( result ) )
                return result;
        }

        method = value[ hint === 'string' ? 'valueOf' : 'toString' ];
        if( typeof method === 'function' ) {
            let result = Reflect.apply( method, value, [] );
            if( isPrimitive( result ) )
                return result;
        }
    }

    throw new TypeError("Cannot convert object to primitive value");
};
```

If you don't need a fully accurate implementation of ToPrimitive but merely something functionally equivalent when used in your application then you can simplify the implementation to:

```js
const toPrimitive = ( value, hint='default' ) => {
    if( isPrimitive( value ) )
        return value;

    let method = value[ Symbol.toPrimitive ];
    if( method != null )  // using != instead of !== is intentional
        return Reflect.apply( method, value, [ hint ] );

    method = value[ hint === 'string' ? 'toString' : 'valueOf' ];
    if( typeof method === 'function' ) {
        let result = Reflect.apply( method, value, [] );
        if( isPrimitive( result ) )
            return result;
    }

    method = value[ hint === 'string' ? 'valueOf' : 'toString' ];
    if( typeof method === 'function' )
        return Reflect.apply( method, value, [] );

    return value;
};
```

and leave throwing exceptions to the caller (the Javascript runtime).

Note that `method != null` (or `method != undefined`) is simply a more concise (and slightly more efficient) way to write `method !== undefined && method !== null`.

Beware to avoid writing something like:

```js
    if( value[ Symbol.toPrimitive ] != null )
        return value[ Symbol.toPrimitive ]( hint );
```

since this performs the `value[ Symbol.toPrimitive ]` property lookup twice, which is an observable difference from the specification (and doing the same property lookup twice can yield different values).

Also don't be tempted to write `method.call( value )` instead of `Reflect.apply( method, value, [] )` since that will not have the same result if the method (rudely) overrides its `call` method.  Using `Function.prototype.call.call( method, value )` is fine, but I wouldn't consider that to be an improvement over using `Reflect.apply`.

You might be able to optimize the case where `hint === 'string'` to:

```js
const toPropertyKey = ( value ) => {
    return Reflect.ownKeys( { [value]: 0 } )[0];
};
```

since I *think* that should be compatible with all uses of ToPrimitive with that hint that are *currently* in the spec, but there is a possibility it could break in the future (e.g. if a future spec introduces bytestrings similar to python3's `bytes` type).  I also don't know whether this is actually faster, that would require testing.

Comment: Could you please explain what this line means: `if(method != undefined) //using != instead of !== is intentional`, why exactly `!=`?

Comment: @Alex `method != undefined` is equivalent to `method !== undefined && method !== null`

Comment: Maybe `value[Symbol.toPrimitive] === null`?
Next, you are checking the `typeof method==='function'`, so I would like to clarify if the `value[Symbol.toPrimitive]` may not be a function?

Comment: The short summary is: if `value[Symbol.toPrimitive]` exists call that, otherwise fall back to trying the legacy `value.valueOf()` and `value.toString()` methods (in that order unless hint is `"string"` in which case `toString()` is tried first).  The subtleties are in how various error cases are specified to be handled: if the first fallback method is a non-function or returns a non-primitive, this is just ignored and the next fallback method is tried.  In contrast, if `[Symbol.toPrimitive]` exists (not `null`/`undefined`) it _must_ be a function that returns a primitive or an error is thrown

Comment: I've added some more comments and explanation to hopefully make things clearer

Comment: Cool, thanks now your idea became clear to me!

Answer (score -1):

```
 proxy_target[Symbol.toPrimitive]("number")
```

Inside of the get handler you could just use Reflect:

```
 get(...args) {
   // ...
   return Reflect.get(...args);
 }
```

Comment: inner can be any type... a number or a string, a function a symbol or undefined, or even another proxy.
I can't just use Reflect since it requires first argument to be an object (You'll get "Reflect.get called on non-object" - if you call it on a number.), while in my case it can be a value.

What I need is to call toPrimitive universly, without handling each possible type of "inner"

Comment: @Yuri: *" What I need is to call toPrimitive universly, without handling each possible type of "inner" "* You only have to treat `null` and `undefined` in a special way. For all else `x[Symbol.toPrimitive]()` will work.

Comment: @FelixKling no, it doesn't work. Just try in Chrome: let x = 5;x[Symbol.toPrimitive](); You'll get 'x[Symbol.toPrimitive] is not a function'